# proper way to use curve_fit to fit a function that takes 1D array input and returns 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit a 2D array (a 10x10 array) with a function defined as follows

```
def musq(dz,y):
    return 1.0/(1.0+y**2*(dz/dz[:,None])**2)
```

This function `musq` takes in 1D array (`dz=np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1)`) and returns a 2D array. When I try to fit the data with this function I get `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`. I understand it must have something to do with the input and output shape mismatch...

But what is the proper way to fit a function with 1D array input that returns a 2D array?

My code and values are as follows

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
dz=np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1)
dat=np.mgrid[0.1:1.1:0.1,0.1:1.1:0.1][0]
ans=curve_fit(musq,dz,dat)
```

Comment: y is the value that needs to be constrained using `curve_fit` will edit to add an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curve fit is not really intended for this type of problem, but luckily you find that it simply calls [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) under the hood which can be used to solve the problem

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np

def musq(x, param):
    return 1.0/(1.0+param**2*(x/x[:,None])**2)

x = np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1)
param = np.arange(10)
y = musq(x, param)

result = least_squares(lambda param: musq(x, param).ravel() - y.ravel(),
                       x0=np.zeros_like(param))
```

Which seems to give the correct result:

```
>>> result.x
array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,
        5.        ,  6.        ,  7.        ,  7.99999996,  8.99999922])
```

Comment: nice! I was just unravelling my `least_squares` as you posted - *darn* :)

Comment: Interesting. The `result` has a strange format though. Will look in detail and see if it fits the data right

Comment: using `ravel()` in both the function and the data seemed to work with the `curve_fit` function too! accepting your answer-will also post mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @Jonas Adler, adding `ravel()` to both the function return as well as the data seemed to do the trick for `curve_fit` directly. Here is my solution (although in this case solution doesn't seem to give a good fit)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def musq(dz,y):
    res=1.0/(1.0+y**2*(dz/dz[:,None])**2)
    return res.ravel()
dz=np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1)
dat=np.mgrid[0.1:1.1:0.1,0.1:1.1:0.1][0]
dat=dat.ravel()
ans=curve_fit(musq,dz,dat)
```